# Oracle SQL aggregate rows into column listagg with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having the following - simplified - layout for tables:

- TABLE blocks (id)
- TABLE content (id, blockId, order, data, type)

`content.blockId` is a foreign key to `blocks.id`. The idea is that in the content table you have many content entries with different types for one block.

I am now looking for a query that can provide me with an aggregation based on a blockId where all the content entries of the 3 different types are concatenated and put into respective columns.

I have already started and found the `listagg` function which is working well, I did the following statement and lists me all the content entries in a column:

```
SELECT listagg(c.data, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.order) FROM content c WHERE c.blockId = 330;
```

Now the concatenated string however contains all the `data` elements of the block in one column. What I would like to achieve is that its put into separate columns based on the type. For example the following content of `content` would be like this:

- 1, 1, 0, "content1", "FRAGMENT"
- 2, 1, 1, "content2", "BULK"
- 3, 1, 3, "content4", "FRAGMENT"
- 4, 1, 2, "content3", "FRAGMENT"

Now I wanted to get as an output 2 columns, one is FRAGMENT and one is BULK, where FRAGMENT contains "content1;content3;content4" and BULK contains "content2"

Is there an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `case`:

```
SELECT listagg(CASE WHEN content = 'FRAGMENT' THEN c.data END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.order) as fragments,
       listagg(CASE WHEN content = 'BULK' THEN c.data END, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.order) as bulks
FROM content c
WHERE c.blockId = 330;
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks, do you happen to know if there is also a possibility to get one row per block if my WHERE is not = 350 but for example > 350? I tried using `OVER (PARTITION BY c.blockId)` and it now creates rows per blockId, but one row for each entry it concatenates, like when there are 25 fragments there are 25 rows with identical content.

Comment: @YanickSalzmann . . . You should ask new questions as *questions*, not as a *comment*.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, if you want it more dynamic, you could pivot the outcome. 
Note, that this will only work for Oracle 11.R2. Here´s an example how it could look like:

```
select * from
(with dataSet as (select 1 idV, 1 bulkid, 0 orderV, 'content1' dataV, 'FRAGMENT' typeV from dual union
                 select 2, 1, 1, 'content2', 'BULK' from dual union
                 select 3, 1, 3, 'content4', 'FRAGMENT' from dual union
                 select 4, 1, 2, 'content3', 'FRAGMENT' from dual)
select typeV, listagg(dataSet.dataV ,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY orderV) OVER (PARTITION BY typeV) dataV from dataSet)
pivot
(
   max(dataV)
   for typeV in ('BULK', 'FRAGMENT')
)
```

O/P

```
Bulk      |  FRAGMENT
-----------------
content2  |  content1,content3,content4
```

The important things here:

`OVER (PARTITION BY typeV)`: this acts like a group by for the listagg, concatinating everything having the same `typeV`.

`for typeV in ('BULK', 'FRAGMENT')`: this will gather the data for `BULK` and `FRAGMENT` and produce separate columns for each.

`max(dataV)` simply to provide a aggregate function, otherwise pivot wont work.

Comment: what appends to 'BULK' aggregate values in your result ?